# Can you choose to discard a card you don't have?

Tags: harry-potter-hogwarts-battle

In "Harry Potter Hogwarts Battle", sometimes there are effects that say: "each player chooses to either discard an item card or else take two damage".

If you don't have an item card, can you choose to discard an item card and not suffer ill effects?

If you're stunned, can you choose to take two damage and not suffer ill effects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [game designer](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/23802402#23802402)

> If you do not have an Item to discard, you must choose the other option, and lose 2 HEALTH.

Comment: I have always played that once you are stunned you can always choose to take the damage option.